# normalize-space not enough for badly presented content

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looking for the 'description' part of [this page](https://www.usine-digitale.fr/annuaire-start-up/innovsante,579743). It contains multiple `<p>` tags. I can retrieve them using this `xpath` :

```
response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text()').extract()
```

But the result is in the form of a list, which does not meet my expectations:

```
['\r\n\tLancée en 2016, la start-up ',
 'est spécialisée dans le développement de ',
 " permettant l'",
 " et l'amélioration de sa prise en charge.",
 '\r\n\t',
 '\r\n\tLa jeune pousse développe ',
 ', un dossier médical numérique universel regroupant toutes les ',
 ' (antécédents, allergies, contre-indications, ordonnances, imagerie, biologie...).',
 '\r\n\t\xa0',
 '\r\n\tLes solutions développées par InnovSanté permettent de faciliter le parcours de soins, de connecter les différents intervenants de la santé et de générer des économies de santé publique.\xa0']
```

I want to add the functionnality of `normalize-space` to retrieve 'clean data' using:

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text())').extract()
```

However, the result is limited to the first `<p>` tag of the previous list showed:

```
['Lancée en 2016, la start-up']
```

Comment: I suppose it's because there are stuff like "" or <strong> in the code source??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string` and `normalize-space` together:

```
description = response.xpath('normalize-space(string(//div[@itemprop="description"]))').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text inside the `strong` tags as well, you'll need to modify your xpath expression to `//div[@itemprop="description"]/p//text()`.
`/` matches direct children in xpath, while `//` matches any descendant.

For a way to do the space normalization take a look at gangabass' answer.

Another way to handle this in scrapy would be using an [item loader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with appropriate input and/or output processors.
For example, using `MapCompose(str.strip)` as the input processor and `Join()` as the output processor results in the following:

```
{'description': 'Lancée en 2016, la start-up InnovSanté est spécialisée dans '
                "le développement de solutions de e-santé permettant l' "
                'optimisation du parcours de soins du patient et '
                "l'amélioration de sa prise en charge.  La jeune pousse "
                'développe Passeport Vital , un dossier médical numérique '
                'universel regroupant toutes les informations relatives au '
                'malade (antécédents, allergies, contre-indications, '
                'ordonnances, imagerie, biologie...).  Les solutions '
                'développées par InnovSanté permettent de faciliter le '
                'parcours de soins, de connecter les différents intervenants '
                'de la santé et de générer des économies de santé publique.'}
```